# Is every continuous function from co-finite topological space to a $T_1$ space is constant?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a co-finite topological space and $Y$ a $T_1$ space. Is it true whether every continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ is constant?

I cannot prove it. I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: Can you see a non-constant continuous map $X \to X$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y=X$ and ask  whether $X$ with the co-finite topology is $T_1$. Now look at $id:X\to X$ what can you say about it?